# Wrong boundary in RegionPlot after RegionUnion

Tags: plotting, regions

I have defined three regions, `Slice1`, `Slice2` and `Slice3`.

```
Slice1 = 
  Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1/(Sqrt[3])}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}];
Slice2 = 
  Polygon[{{0, 0}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1/(Sqrt[3])}, {-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}];
Slice3 = 
  Polygon[{{0, 
     0}, {-1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}, {0, -2/Sqrt[3]}, {1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}}];

CombinedSlice = RegionUnion[Slice1, Slice2, Slice3];
RegionPlot[CombinedSlice, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

When I `RegionPlot` the combined plot, `Slice3` does not have correct boundaries. The boundary shows up correctly when I plot `Slice3` individually.

[image]

I am using Mathematica 12.0

Comment: It looks like a bug in `RegionUnion[` in cases where we have disjoint regions or regions that have no interior point in common: Try e.g.: CombinedSlice = RegionUnion[Slice1, Slice2]; However, if we have some interior common points: `Slice4 = Polygon[{{-0.001, -0.50}, {0.001, -0.5}, {0.001, 0.1}, {-0.001, 0.1}}]; RegionPlot[CombinedSlice, AspectRatio -> Automatic]` it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such bug also appear in 12.2. We had to draw the boundary and interior separately.

```
Show[RegionPlot[{RegionBoundary@CombinedSlice}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Red],
 RegionPlot[CombinedSlice, BoundaryStyle -> None]]
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, can this affect the result if I numerically integrate a function over the whole region? Is it a good idea to integrate over the individual regions and add them?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi It doesn't affect the result. For example, `{CombinedSlice // Area,
 Integrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] CombinedSlice],
 ArcLength[RegionBoundary@CombinedSlice],
 3*ArcLength[RegionBoundary@Slice1] // N}`